# coffescript and jquery ajax call

Tags: jquery, ajax, coffeescript

I am trying to make ajax call with coffescript and jquery and update form input type with result, but my input gets updated with [object XMLDocument] instead returned text

Here is coffescript code I use.

```
$ ->
 $('#get-mac').live 'click', (e) =>
     e.preventDefault()
     podaci = {broj : $('#contract_no').val(), action : 'get-mac-ua'}
     $.ajax '/hhh'
         type: 'POST'
         data: podaci
         datatype: 'text'
         success: (data) ->
             if data == 'False'
                 $('#mac').removeAttr "readonly"
                 alert 'Ne postoji MAC adresa na UA, upiši ručno'
             else
                 $('#mac').val data
                 $('#mac').removeAttr "readonly"
                 $('#contract_no').attr "readonly", true
```

here is old js version, that works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#get-mac").live('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var podaci = {broj : $('#contract_no').val(), action : 'get-mac-ua'};
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: '/hhh',
      data: podaci,
      dataType: 'html',
      success: function(data){
          if(data == "False")
              {
                  $('#mac').removeAttr("readonly");
                  alert('Ne postoji MAC adresa na UA, upiši ručno');
              }
          else
              {
                  $('#mac').val(data);
                  $('#mac').removeAttr("readonly");
                  $('#contract_no').attr("readonly", true)
              }
        }
    });
  });
});
```

Comment: do `console.log(data);` and see in the firebug console what do you get, you will have to do `data.property`

Comment: console.log(data);
ReferenceError: data is not defined

Comment: have you considered changing `dataType` to `html`, `dataType:"html"`

Comment: same thing with dataType:"html"

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The significant difference between your JS code and your CoffeeScript is simply that you changed `dataType` to `datatype`. Capitalization matters! :)